# Input doesn't pass through into attached container with R session

Tags: r, docker, shinyproxy

I was trying to do some debugging in R code when it's already on the container.

After doing `docker attach #container-id`, I attach as expected to the running process, I get to see the browser prompt as well. However, I cannot interact with the R session due to the input not passing through to R session. Commands that I enter stay in a buffer and only get executed in the local bash after the container detaches.

R session is started through ShinyProxy that spins up a Docker container with R instance in which the following script is run:

```
#!/bin/bash
R -e "shiny::runApp(host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"
```

I'm connecting to the machine with docker from windows using putty. How can I make my input pass through into the attacked R container?

Comment: I suspect this may be do to buffering going on when the container is run without a pseudo TTY. What is the command used to start the container that you are attaching to?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know as it is being done through ShinyProxy and I have not dug through their code yet to see how they start the Docker instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be due to putty which seems to send something to the input resulting in the closing of Browser prompt.

Using ssh client from git provided a solution.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Which SSH client did you end up using?